# program doesnt read the else clause

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a simple program that doesnt read else clause in php -
**This reads the if clause and prints Operation not possible ! even if i havent submitted any form to this page. Instead it should display No actions yet !!**

```
<?php

    include "connection.php";

    $dt = $_GET['datetime'];
    $dttm = strtotime($dt);
    echo $dttm;

    if($dttm < time())
    {
     echo "<center><strong> Operation not possible !</strong></center>"; 
    }

    else if (!empty($_GET['but1'])) { echo "but1";
     }
    else if (!empty($_GET['but2'])) { echo "but2";
     }
    else if (!empty($_GET['but3'])) { echo "but3";
     }

    else
     {
        echo "No actions yet !!";
     }
?>
```

Can anyone help me point out **my mistake** in here ... Thanks!

Comment: Exactly how is this "not working"?

Comment: @David it doesnt read the else clause when no other conditions are true

Comment: And how have you verified this?  What are the exact inputs and behaviors observed here?  "It doesn't read the else clause" isn't really helpful.

Comment: Remove the space between elseif

Comment: @NitinRajan the space is valid http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: On a side note - the <center> tag is not supported in HTML5. Maybe time to move away from it

Comment: So what values of `$_GET['datetime']` haven't worked when they should?

Comment: @David i am submitting a form from an iframe into this parent page which 'GETS' the data. Now if there are no submissions then the parent page must execute the else clause.

Comment: @Kaus: This sounds like a good opportunity to familiarize yourself with some basic debugging.  Use your browser's debugging tools to examine the actual HTTP requests and responses taking place and the values being sent on those requests, turn on error reporting and logging in your PHP installation, add debugging output to the PHP code, etc.  "It doesn't work" isn't where you stop trying, you can discover much more helpful information from the system that's right in front of you.

Comment: @MarkBaker $_GET['datetime'] works perfectly when i have submitted the form from iframe to this parent page. But when there are no submissions it is still showing "Operation not possible !"

Comment: @David i forgot to mention this-
problem is that this program is reading only the if clause even if it is false when there are no form submisssions otherwise it is working as it should !

Comment: @Kaus: `even if it is false` - Nope, try again.  `if` blocks are evaluated when the condition is *true*, not when it is *false*.  Stop assuming your condition is false and blaming the PHP engine for being broken.  The condition is, in fact, true.  In the *vast majority* of cases, when you believe that your code is correct and that the language itself is fundamentally broken, it is because you have an assumption that you need to eliminate in your testing.

Answer (score 2):

From your comment on the question:

> But when there are no submissions it is still showing "Operation not possible !"

That's because the original `if` block is resolving to `true`.  (The value of `$dttm`, which may be `false` or `-1` if there was an error parsing the query string value, is less than `time()`.)  When an `if` condition is `true` then the system isn't going to go to the `else` block.  `if` and `else` are, [by definition](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php), mutually exclusive.

It sounds like you may want to include an `empty()` check in the first condition.  Something like this:

```
if(!empty($_GET['datetime'])) {
    $dt = $_GET['datetime'];
    $dttm = strtotime($dt);
    echo $dttm;
    if($dttm < time()) {
        echo "<center><strong> Operation not possible !</strong></center>";
    }
} else if //...
```

Or however you want to structure the set of conditionals.  The point being that it seems like you want to process that first block only *if* a value was submitted in the first place.

Comment: $dttm is having garbage values to be precise. Am i correct?

Comment: @Kaus: Not really "garbage" values, but values which can be legitimately compared to other values (such as `time()`).

Comment: now my else if statements arent executing because they are dependent on $dt = $_GET['datetime'];